# EADemo[310:20709] Couldn't find the "com.apple.private.externalaccessory.showallaccessories" entitlement

Tags: ios

I was trying to connect to accessory using EADemo(Demo application provided by Apple) but while running it i am getting this error. 
This issue is open in Apple forum ( https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61646 ) also, Please Help

Answer (score 0):

iOS requires all supported external accessories to be whitelisted. To connect to the external accessory, you need to add the protocol names to info.plist. Use the key 'UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols' or search by text 'Supported external accessory protocols'.

It's an array. For each device you need to get a protocol name that looks like mirrored URL (i.e. com.accessory.device) Once you will whitelist accessory you are planing to use, it will stop showing you this error.